# DialogFragment without animation

Tags: android, android-animation, dialogfragment

I have DialogFragment with slide up animation on show. After clicking a button in dialog I start another activity without dismissing my dialog. The problem is, every time I finish an acitivity, the animation runs on dialog. Is there any way to turn off dialog animation after dialog is shown?

Answer (score 0):

The situation sounds weird: if it's a DialogFragment that is attached to the first Activity, then how is it that you would keep the dialog showing when you start a different Activity? Or are you just re-starting the DialogFragment for both of your Activities?

Anyway, without knowing more details, there are a couple of things you can try.

1. If it really is the same DialogFragment instance that is running the same animation twice, then you can add a boolean in the dialog that is initially false, and gets set to true when you fire the animation. Then only fire the animation when the boolean is false.
2. If you are starting the same DialogFragment twice, for each of the two Activities you describe, then you can use setArguments(Bundle) right after constructing the DialogFragment, and add a boolean argument that says whether you want to show the animation.